# Can't create new nuxt project. Problem using npm init nuxt-app nuxt-hello-world

Tags: nuxt.js

Everything works till line 30 and then I get:

```
31 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 1 files
32 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
33 silly logfile done cleaning log files
34 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/create-nuxt-app 149ms (cache revalidated)
35 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
36 timing command:init Completed in 249ms
37 verbose stack Error: command failed
37 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:53:27)
37 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
37 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
37 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
38 verbose cwd /Volumes/My Passport 1/myusername/mydirect
39 verbose Darwin 23.2.0
40 verbose node v20.11.0
41 verbose npm  v10.2.4
42 error code 127
43 error path /Volumes/My Passport 1//myusername/mydirect
44 error command failed
45 error command sh -c create-nuxt-app nuxt-hello-world
46 verbose exit 127
47 timing npm Completed in 333ms
48 verbose code 127
```

I am using a Mac. vue version gives me @vue/cli 5.0.8
I could also create a vue application and execute it without any problems
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We need to use

`npx nuxi@latest init nuxt-hello-world`